# get the second item in a key

Tags: python, networkx

Using graphs in network x i can call the following attributes for node n from graph G:

```
G.node[n]  

{'type': 'a', 'pos': [0.22, 0.33]}
```

I can access different attributes (keys) like the following

```
G.node[n]['pos']
```

But I cannot figure out how can I access only the first or second element of 'pos'? i.e.

```
0.22
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you the first element:

```
G.node[n]['pos'][0]
```

Comment: downgrade accepted! I thought i had done this, found something very stupid in code!

Comment: @user1320502 I've withdrawn the downvote, which was, as much as anything, for not showing what you had tried.